# How to insert multiple rows of a pandas dataframe into Azure Synapse SQL DW using pyodbc?

Tags: azure, pyodbc, azure-synapse

I am using pyodbc to establish connection with Azure Synapse SQL DW. The connection is successfully established. However when it comes to inserting a pandas dataframe into the database, I am getting an error when I try inserting multiple rows as values.  However, it works if I insert rows one by one. Inserting multiple rows together as values used to work fine with AWS Redshift and MS SQL, but fails with Azure Synapse SQL DW. I think the Azure Synapse SQL is T-SQL and not MS-SQL. Nonetheless, I am unable to find any relevant documentation as well.

I have a pandas df named 'df' that looks like this:

```
student_id  admission_date
    1          2019-12-12
    2          2018-12-08
    3          2018-06-30
    4          2017-05-30
    5          2020-03-11
```

This code below works fine

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
#conn object below is the pyodbc 'connect' object

    batch_size = 1
    i = 0
    chunk = df[i:i+batch_size]
    conn.autocommit = True
    sql = 'insert INTO {} values {}'.format('myTable', ','.join(
        str(e) for e in zip(chunk.student_id.values, chunk.admission_date.values.astype(str))))
    print(sql)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

As you can see, it's inserting just 1 row of the 'df'. So, yes, I  can loop through and insert one by one but it takes hell lot of time when it comes dataframes of larger sizes

This code below doesn't work when I try to insert all rows together
    import pandas as pd
    import pyodbc

```
batch_size = 5
i = 0
chunk = df[i:i+batch_size]
conn.autocommit = True
sql = 'insert INTO {} values {}'.format('myTable', ','.join(
        str(e) for e in zip(chunk.student_id.values, chunk.admission_date.values.astype(str))))
print(sql)
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
```

The error I  get this one below:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000]
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at
>   line: 1, column: 74: Incorrect syntax near ','. (103010)
>   (SQLExecDirectW)")

This is the sample SQL query for 2 rows which fails:

```
insert INTO myTable values (1, '2009-12-12'),(2, '2018-12-12')
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because Azure Synapse SQL does not support multi-row insert via the values constructor.
One work around is to chain "select (value list) union all". Your pseudo SQL should look like so:

```sql
insert INTO {table}
select {chunk.student_id.values}, {chunk.admission_date.values.astype(str)} union all
...
select {chunk.student_id.values}, {chunk.admission_date.values.astype(str)}
```

Answer (score 0):

COPY statement in Azure Synapse Analytics is a better way for loading your data in Synapse SQL Pool.

```
COPY INTO test_parquet
FROM 'https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/myblobcontainer/folder1/*.parquet'
WITH (
    FILE_FORMAT = myFileFormat,
    CREDENTIAL=(IDENTITY= 'Shared Access Signature', SECRET='<Your_SAS_Token>')
)
```

You can save your pandas dataframe into blob storage, and then trigger the copy command using execute method.